# How much energy would be required to make one tea cup full of Earl Gray tea at 100F?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, temperature

On the TV show "Star Trek: The Next Generation", Captain Picard is often pictured using a replicator to materialize a cup of "Earl Gray tea, hot". Besides wondering what they do with all the empty teacups, I've often wondered just how much pure energy is contained in that cup of tea.

Comment: Note that $100^\circ\mathrm{F}$ is not what I would describe as a "hot" cup of tea. Maybe "tepid" if I was feeling generous, but more likely "luke warm".

Comment: @dmckee Do you suppose Picard had to specify at some time exactly what he considered hot? By the way, presumably it takes additional energy for the replicator to work, but any energy overhead should be overlooked.

Comment: @Gert OP is asking about the total energy content of a physical object. Is a cup of tea considered a 'fictional machine' where you live?

Comment: @Gert As I said in an earlier comment, the only energy to be considered in the question is the cup of tea itself.

Comment: This depends on the starting conditions.  What does the replicator have to start with?  Can it beam $72F$ water from a holding tank?  Elemental $O_2$ and $H_2$?  Raw energy to create quarks and leptons?

Comment: This might be a better question for scifi.stackexchange, where there are probably more people with knowledge of the in-universe explanation for how replicators work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "materializing" means creating matter from energy, then a 250 ml cup of water will contain approximately 250 g of water with a smidge of other molecules. Add another 100 g for the cup (light weight... this is space). From $E=mc^2$, you find an energy content of roughly $3\cdot 10^{15}~\rm{ J}$.

Note that the thermal energy content (difference between "cold" and "hot") is many orders of magnitude smaller than this - completely negligible.

If we assume the mass of the Enterprise to be about $3\cdot10^9~\rm{kg}$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E))), this corresponds to the kinetic energy of the entire starship moving at 3000 m/s (Mach 10).

I'm thinking that it would be cheaper to get a Keurig...

Comment: I guess the inertial dampers smooth out the 'stomping on the brakes' feeling that occurs every time Picard wants his cuppa. I posed this question as a microcosm of the amount of energy the Enterprise must expend in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to do is to discard the tea itself, because it not only accounts for a truly miniscule overall volume within the beverage, but also it is composed of molecules enormously more complex than those of water and hence we would be here all day. The second thing to do is discard the cup - it is too much of an unknown quantity in its many possible sizes and compositions. Just water, then. He'll have to fetch a cup from somewhere.

The energy required to heat a 250ml cup of water from absolute zero to 100F, using relevant figures of specific heat of water from [engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-thermal-properties-d_162.html), is approximately 325,306 Joules, or 325kJ.

Heat = mass * specific heat * temperature change.

However, if you mean the absolute amount of energy, or relativistic energy, necessarily manifest in the mass itself of that water, it becomes a bigger calculation. We'll assume it's totally pure and that 27.78 grams of that water is hydrogen, with the remaining 223.22 grams being oxygen. These figures follow from their respective masses.

Using e = mc^2 for the energy of all that hydrogen, we get e = 8,328,234,483.24 J, or about 8.328 GJ. Again for the oxygen, we get 66,919,672,474.8 J, or 66.919 GJ.

Combining the relativistic energies we get 75,247,906,958 or 75.247 GJ. Adding the now paltry amount of heat energy in a 100F cup of water we get 75,248,232,264 J or 75.248 GJ.

Finally, we ought to involve the bond energy of molecular water, which I find to be 458.9 kJ/mol, for our 250ml of water would be roughly 6,373,611 J or 6.373 MJ. Our total energy is now 75,248,232,264 + 6,373,611 or 75,254,605,875. That's 75.254 GJ.

Comment: I think that the teacup itself represents a significant enough mass that it should be considered. That's about 6 ounces of mass. Say, 1.5288e+16 joules? Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Very well. I had presumed that the tea was the real consumable and as such it would make sense to just bring a cup, rather than generating a huge number of such very durable objects.

Comment: You calculate the mass-energy of the hydrogen and oxygen separately... Is that accurate to the mass-energy of the resultant amount of molecular water? I would think the chemical bonding would change the final energy significantly.

Comment: It would appear that the bond energy for a mole of water is approximately 458 kJ. Not terribly significant when you consider relativistic energy, but I'll add it anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer to this is really $mc^2 + \epsilon$ for almost any conceivable object you'd want to hold or, really, be anywhere near at all, so all you really need is the total mass of the thing (tea and cup).

Comment: And this answer smells wrong: if the total mass is $0.35\textrm{kg}$, and $c^2 = 9\times10^{16}$, then the total energy is something like $3.2\times 10^{15}\textrm{J}$.